# Can "once" and "since" be followed by a V-ing clause?

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, conjunctions, gerunds

Consider these examples:

> - *Since the board realized* that the figures are increasing, they have been searching for a new campaign.
> - *Once the board realized* that the figures are increasing, they began searching for a new campaign.

Can they be rewritten as "since realizing" and "once realizing"?

Answer (score 2):

They can, but in any case *are* should be *were*, because the ‘that’ clause is a reporting clause.

Answer (score 2):

The conjunction *once* has only one meaning (approximating to *when* or *as soon as*) and needs to be followed by the subject of the dependent clause it introduces. You cannot reduce the clause to:

> ?Once realizing that the figures are increasing, the board ... .

The temporal conjunction *since*, with the sense of *starting at a point in time (and continuing)*, can be reduced in this way:

> Since realizing that the figures are increasing, the board ... .

However, if the conjunction *since* has its other sense (approximating to *as* or *because*), it cannot be reduced. Example:

> Since you speak Russian, you may be able to understand this
>   letter.
>
> *Since speaking Russian, you may be able to understand this letter.

Answer (score 0):

It can shift the places as:

Once realizing the increase in figures, they began searching for a new campaign. and same for the other..:)

Comment: I don't think _realizing_ can have a direct object in this way.

Comment: Yes – though the standard dictionary definition of the intended sense doesn't inform the reader of this restriction on what the DO can be: realize - _be fully aware or cognizant of_  (WordNet 3.0). _realize the importance of the increase in numbers_ **but not** (in this sense) _realize the increase in numbers_ **–** _notice the increase in numbers_ works.